Generate an .eml file including the MSIP label
I'm currently coding an email generator using Python and its native email package.
I take an Excel file in input and generate several .eml files as the output.
The goal isn't to send them automatically but to let the user open them individually in Outlook, brings some modifications and decide whether he want to send it or not.
Everything works perfectly fine excepting that the user has to choose for each email the MSIP label to use, I would like to specify one by default to make his life easier.
Rather than focusing solely on Python, I'm wondering if it's possible to include an MSIP label directly within an .eml file format, or if this is a proprietary feature limited to formats like .msg ?
The idea is to save the .eml file, close it and get the MSIP label automatically applied on the file open.
Any help will be very appreciated !
Thank you 
I tried desperately to add a "msip_labels" header
msg = MIMEText("Loreum ipsum","plain")
msg['Subject'] = "The email subject"
msg['From'] = "myemail@mail.beautyemail"
msg['To'] = "abeautifulemail@mail.beautyemail"

msg['msip_labels'] = "MSIP_Label_aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee_Name=Secret"

